# Math software to plot functions of the kind $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb C$ in 3D?

Tags: computer-algebra-systems, sagemath, maxima-software

Im experimenting with different computer algebra systems trying to plot a function of the kind

$$f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb C$$

in 3D, but I dont know a simple and direct solution in any CAS to this kind of plot. To context the question I will leave an elementary function and I will be glad to see some example, the simpler and direct the best, to plot it in 3d in any CAS.

Let $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb C$ such that $x\mapsto i^x$

My interest is mainly in free software like Sage, Sympy, Maxima or Axiom. I tried too Geogebra but it doesnt support in any way complex numbers so I cant plot the above in any direct way.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For reference, see also at https://ask.sagemath.org/question/35284/how-i-can-plot-functions-of-the-kind-fbbb-rtobbb-c-in-3d/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Mathematica is not free you can use it for free via Wolfram's Open Programming Lab - https://lab.open.wolframcloud.com/

Here is my go at your graph using it:
[image]

Comment: Ah, thank you, I dont knew this wolframcloud, seems an intermediate solution between paid software and completely free one.

Comment: It has some limitations compared to full Mathematica but from my experience these are generally around limiting the time/amount of computations. So if you aren't doing hundreds of these types of graphs you should be fine.

Comment: Well, I see that the same "trick" of parametric plot work for [sage](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwrSCxKzE0tKcpMji_IyS8xTtGIrtApSk3MiS9ILCrR8Iyr0NTJzE1MR3BjdTQqdHQNDXQMDTR1SlIrSkqLUm2VilJTlDQBQZUaOg==&lang=sage).

Comment: Can you post that "trick" in Sage as an answer or update?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I found by now is a parametric plot in Geogebra, unexpectedly expressions like $\Re(i^x)$ and $\Im(i^x)$ works inside of parametric curves in geogebra.

Then the code

```
Curve[u, real(ί^u), imaginary(ί^u), u, -10, 10]
```

works perfectly. You can check it [here](https://ggbm.at/ecHqwC4d).